# How can I get data validation rules to apply to scroll bars in Excel?

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, scrollbar

I have a simple budgeting spreadsheet in Excel where inputting a figure for any individual spending category (e.g. 'Travel expenses') is invalidated if it would push spending above income for the month.

I also have scroll bars set up for each spending category, so I can make adjustments without typing numbers into cells directly. However, the data validations do not apply to the scroll bars: it will let you set categories to values which would exceed monthly income by adjusting the scroll bars.

Is it possible to apply the same data validation to the scroll bars as to manual input of the cells, so that I get an error and am prevented from adjusting a category to a level that would exceed monthly income?

I think this is covered in the above section.

Comment: You will have to link code to your scroll bars and manage the min/max validation from the code.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j9h54Nf4Pgrs8jO2hs3A?e=kBefnn)/screenshot(s) refer:

VBA (below) required.

**Set up**

[image: references]

names range(s):

- D4: *max_*
- C4: *linked*

---

Scrollbar module (to associate VB code see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/scrollbar-control-scroll-event-example)):

```
Sub ScrollBar1_Change()
    On Error Resume Next
    L = Range("linked").Value
    M = Range("max_").Value
    c = ActiveCell.AddressLocal
    If L > M Then
        R = MsgBox("Max exceeded")

        Range("linked").Value = M
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Scroll Bar 1")).Select
    With Selection
        .Max = M
    End With
    Range(c).Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

In respective sheet include following (to create code for specific sheet: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/run-macro-cells-change)):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call ScrollBar1_Change

End Sub
```

---

[image: Example in action]

Features:

- *max_* (D4): sum of col G:G (e.g. 'monthly income' per Q) need not be selected for macro to run (only if its value or that of *linked* [C4] change)
- whenever max_ changes so too does scroll bar max  (preventative measure 1 RE: ensuring spend > income not selected)
- whenever *max_* (notwithstanding as a function or user input value) falls below *selected* value, msg box displayed and selected value updated to *max_* value (to preserve function if this is used for *max_*)

---